# Percentage not working with div in div

Tags: html, wordpress

I am using the X theme in wordpress
I am trying to create a div within the main container. This should be really simple
just a box within a box. I keep trying to use the % to get it to fit but every time I switch from px to 5 the div disappears.

Any ideas?

Comment: you shall share the relevant part of the code, otherwise its impossible to get help;

Answer (score 0):

I guess the % won't work as expected. Try to use a em value instead. Begin with smaller values and increase until it fits. Em will scale the div according to browser / screen size. It's just a guess because you didn't provide the code but it could work. ;)